# Mapping boolean with np.vectorize in Python

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have this two columns in pandas df:

```
     seconds       min
0              52  0.866667
1               5  0.083333
2              10  0.166667
3               5  0.083333
4              16  0.266667
197           144  2.400000
```

I wanted to convert seconds in minutes in the ['min'] column only when ['seconds'] is greater than 60, otherwise it should be empty.

I tried to transform ['min'] column in boolean:

```
    x = df['min'] = np.array(df['seconds'].apply(lambda x: True if x >60 else False))
```

and I got the boolean values, then I tried to map it:

```
    mapping = [df['seconds']/60]
    result = np.vectorize(lambda i:mapping[i], x)
```

but I got in return:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Is this correct way to do it or is there another simpler solution?

Output:

```
    seconds       min
0              52  
1               5  
2              10  
3               5  
4              16  
197           144  2.400000
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from 'True' and 'False'

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that, but I got in return IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: Also looks like there should be a comma ```result = np.vectorize(lambda i:mapping[i], x)```

Comment: @Techniquab Yes, thanks. I corrected it. I updated the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about how to use your vectorize approach, but the following will work

```py
df.loc[df['seconds']<60,'min'] = 0
df.loc[df['seconds']>60,'min'] = df['seconds'][df['seconds']>60] /60
```

Comment: I see, thanks. I wanted to map the [df['seconds']>60] /60 where I had False.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'True' and 'False' are strings not boolean. Booleans have not quotes